# getting error during deployment contract through hardhat

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my contract through hardhat it was successfully compilling but when I try to
deploy it on goerli network it giving an error
[image: I did'nt get a key of contract after compilation]

I am using this three commands for deployment

> npx hardhat clean
> npx hardhat compile
> npx hardhat run scripts/deployNewNFT.js --network goerli

I want the reason why it did'nt  deployed after successfully compilation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter the correct infura url.